# Reformatting Data into another Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing topic modeling for a number of text files in a folder. I've imported data from a final comprehensive text file into excel. It's formatted like below. The whole numbers represent topics and the decimals represent what percentage of that topic took place in that text file.

> | C |   | D   |      | E |   | F   |   |
>   G | | H |      |  I  |  | J
>          |
>  | 2 |  |0.85|  |
>   1 | |0.05|  | 0 | |
>   0.012|    | 3 | | 0.004 |.... 
>  | 0 | |0.50|  | 2 | |0.31|  | 3 | |0.146 |   | 1 | | 0.068 | ...

The topic numbers need to become column headers, and the percentages go below. I need the data to be reformatted into another sheet in the following format:

> | D |         | E   | 
>        | F     |   | G
>       |   
>  | 0 | 
>          |1     |
>      | 2     | |
>   3      | ... | n |  
>  | 0.012 |
>   |0.05|    | 0.85 | |0.004| 
>  | 0.50   |
>   |0.068|  | 0.31 | |0.146|

Each text file will have the same number of topics, but the number of topics could vary. So, this example has 4 topics, but another could have 20, 25, etc. I tried to use the items method, but it looks like I would have to hard code the values in there. Is there another way to do this?

Here's what my source data looks like:

[Source Data in Excel](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39753409/sourceData.jpg)

I tried this but kept getting stuck:

```
Sub Items_Ex()

Dim myColumn As Long myRow = 2
While Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(2, myColumn).Value <> ""

Dim myRow As Long myRow = 3
While Worksheets("Input_Format_A").Cells(myRow, 3).Value <> ""
Dim d As Dictionary Dim a, i 'Create some variables
Set d = New Dictionary
d.Add "1", Worksheets("Input_Text").Cells(1, 8).Value
d.Add "2", Worksheets("Input_Text").Cells(1, 6).Value
d.Add "3", Worksheets("Input_Text").Cells(1, 4).Value 'Do until there are no more topics
a = d.Items 'Get the items For i = 0 To d.Count - 1 'Iterate the array
Debug.Print a(i) 'Print item Next

Debug.Print d.Item("b")
myRow = myRow + 1
Wend
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Sorry, will add it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First it gets the **highest topic in the source range** of the source sheet (active sheet).
- Then each topic number is searched in source range and when found then **the neighbour is copied to new sheet**

  ```
  Private Const NEW_SHEET_NAME As String = "NewSheetName"
  Private Const FIRST_TARGET_ROW = 9
  Private Const FIRST_TARGET_COLUMN = 4
  Private Const FIRST_SOURCE_CELL As String = "c2"

  Sub test()

      Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
      Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
      If (sourceSheet.UsedRange Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

      Dim sourceRange As Range
      Set sourceRange = Application.Intersect(sourceSheet.UsedRange, sourceSheet.Range(FIRST_SOURCE_CELL & ":" & sourceSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address))

      Dim maxTopic As Byte
      maxTopic = CByte(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(sourceRange))

      Dim data() As Variant
      data = sourceRange.Value

      Dim newSheet As Worksheet
      Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
      newSheet.Name = NEW_SHEET_NAME

      Dim topic As Byte
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim j As Integer
      Dim item As Variant
      For topic = 0 To maxTopic
          newSheet.Cells(FIRST_TARGET_ROW, FIRST_TARGET_COLUMN + topic).Value = topic
          For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
              For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
                  item = data(i, j)
                  If (IsEmpty(item)) Then GoTo next_item
                  If (item = topic) Then
                      With newSheet
                          If (j + 1 <= UBound(data, 2)) Then
                              .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, FIRST_TARGET_COLUMN + topic).End(xlUp).Row + 1, FIRST_TARGET_COLUMN + topic).Value = data(i, j + 1)
                          End If
                      End With
                  End If
  next_item:
              Next j
          Next i
      Next topic

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm very inexperienced with vba. How would you edit this to grab every filled cell starting at cell C2 in a sheet and paste the reformatted information into a named sheet starting at cell D9?

Comment: I have added some code which adds name to new sheet and sets target and source range. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: The updated code isn't quite working right. It's grabbing information from column B. I need it to get everything to the right and below cell C2.

Comment: It is difficult without to see how your source data look like. Could you post the screen shot of your source sheet? Or post the source data somehow?

Comment: You should be able to see it from this link. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39753409/sourceData.jpg

Comment: I corrected the code so now data = sourceRange.Value, try it and let me know if it works now.